# How to DoubleTap using Android UI Automator

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I am trying to double tap on a view using Android UI Automator tool, but there is no API to double tap. Is there any other way to Double tap using ui automator.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to double tap on? Which element?

Comment: Hi Smriti, Thanks for your comment. I want to double click on image view, but there is no direct api from ui automator. But finally i got the solution for this.  I configured the delay between the events by using Configurator(http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/Configurator.html) api

Comment: UiObject selectImage = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.RelativeLayout").index(3));
     
    
Configurator cc = Configurator.getInstance();
cc.setActionAcknowledgmentTimeout(40);
  
selectImage.click();
selectImage.click();

Comment: You can also use directly Thread.sleep(time in ms) for delay

Comment: No, For double tap it will not work. for the double tap you need to set 40 milliseconds delay between the two click events. It was less than the default time. if you want wait more than this default time then you can use Thread.sleep(time).

Comment: Please use the search function before posting a question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396646/how-to-press-a-button-twice-using-google-uiautomator

Comment: The question @SatyaAttili seems different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396646/how-to-press-a-button-twice-using-google-uiautomator because he's specifically asking about a *double tap*, a single action, not two taps on the same object which is two actions.

Comment: The approach @SatyaAttili suggested using `setActionAcknowledgmentTimeout(40)` worked for me.

Comment: Adding `setActionAcknowledgmentTimeout(40)` also seems to help fuse other combinations of actions besides `UiObject.click()`.  For example, I needed to automate a zoom-in action on a map which involved `UiObject.click()` followed by `UiObject.swipeDown(30)` (also zoom-out `UiObject.click()` followed by `UiObject.swipeUp(30)`.  It didn't work without adding `setActionAcknowledgmentTimeout(40)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Gesture interaction with the device
Click on the screen

d.click(x, y)
Double click

d.double_click(x, y)
d.double_click(x, y, 0.1) # default duration between two click is 0.1s
Long click on the screen

d.long_click(x, y)
d.long_click(x, y, 0.5) # long click 0.5s (default)
Swipe

d.swipe(sx, sy, ex, ey)
d.swipe(sx, sy, ex, ey, 0.5) # swipe for 0.5s(default)

d.drag(sx, sy, ex, ey)
d.drag(sx, sy, ex, ey, 0.5) # swipe for 0.5s(default)
Swipe points

# swipe from point(x0, y0) to point(x1, y1) then to point(x2, y2)
# time will speed 0.2s bwtween two points
d.swipe_points([(x0, y0), (x1, y1), (x2, y2)], 0.2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way:

```
img.click();
Thread.sleep(50);
img.click();
```