# How to make 10 fast clicks [UIautomator]

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

Im trying to make fast 10 clicks on the button using this

```
public static void fastClicks(String text, int index) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        UiObject settingsButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId(text).index(index));
        Configurator cc = Configurator.getInstance();
        cc.setActionAcknowledgmentTimeout(10);
          for (int i = 1; i < 11; ++i){
        settingsButton.click();
        System.out.println("clicked "+ i + " ");
    }
    }
```

yes it makes 10 clicks but first click have a little delay or something like that so it doesn't work properly. All I need this is 10 ritmic clicks with same delay from 1 click to 10. How can I improve this code? Thank you :)

else I tried this code

```
 public static void fastClicks(String text, int index, int clicksCount) throws Exception {
        UiObject settingsButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId(text).index(index));
        for(int currentClickIndex = 0; currentClickIndex < clicksCount; currentClickIndex++) {
            if(settingsButton.exists()) {
                settingsButton.click();
                Thread.sleep(40);
                System.out.println("clicked " + currentClickIndex + " times");
            }
        }
    }
```

still nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'll try to make this a proper answer.

Because this behavior is only seen by the first click, it might occurs because some configurations were made before (or after) the action itself. For instance:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/master/uiautomator/library/core-src/com/android/uiautomator/core/UiObject.java

```
public boolean click() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
    [...]
    AccessibilityNodeInfo node = findAccessibilityNodeInfo(mConfig.getWaitForSelectorTimeout());
    [...]
}

protected AccessibilityNodeInfo findAccessibilityNodeInfo(long timeout) {
    [...]
    while (currentMills <= timeout) {
        node = getQueryController().findAccessibilityNodeInfo(getSelector());
        if (node != null) {
            break;
        } else {
            // does nothing if we're reentering another runWatchers()
            UiDevice.getInstance().runWatchers();
        }
       [...]
    }
    return node;
}
```

To avoid this, you can try getting the object's bounds first and then calling `getUiDevice().click(...)` directly:

```
    UiObject settingsButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId(text).index(index));
    Rect bounds = settingsButton.getBounds();
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; ++i){
         getUiDevice().click(bounds.centerX(), bounds.centerY());
         System.out.println("clicked "+ i + " ");
    }
```

(as suggested by @Rami Kuret https://stackoverflow.com/a/17497559/2723645)